# ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([1, 64])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1]))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I am trying to build a neural network, and I know that my target size is 1, 64 because my batch size is 64. Could you tell me how to get my input size 64 if my data is in a .csv file and it is a 5 columns, 10 rows file?

```
from asyncore import loop
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(torch.cuda.is_available())

# Prepare the data and normalize
data = pd.read_csv("c:\\Users\\zyman\\Desktop\\NeuralNetworkTrainingData.csv")

# Convert the data to a NumPy array from Pandas DataFrame
data = data.to_numpy()

# Normalize the data
data_min = np.min(data, axis=0)
data_max = np.max(data, axis=0)
normalized_data = (data - data_min) / (data_max - data_min)

# Prepare input and output data
X = normalized_data[:-1]  # Input sequence (open, high, low, close, volume) until the second last candle
Y = (data[1:, 3] > data[:-1, 3]).astype(int)  # Output labels (1 if next closing price is higher, 0 otherwise)

# Convert data to PyTorch tensorsfile
X_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(X).float()
Y_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(Y).float()

# Split the data into training and testing sets
split_index = int(0.8 * len(X))  # 80% for training, 20% for testing
X_train, X_test = X_tensor[:split_index], X_tensor[split_index:]
Y_train, Y_test = Y_tensor[:split_index], Y_tensor[split_index:]

#Transfer tensors to GPU
dev = "cuda:0" 
device = torch.device(dev)
X_train = X_train.to(device)
Y_train = Y_train.to(device)


# Define the LSTM model
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        _, (h_n, _) = self.lstm(x)
        out = self.fc(h_n[-1])
        return torch.sigmoid(out)


input_size = X_train.shape[1]
hidden_size = 200
output_size = 1

# Create a list to store the models
models = []

# Train and create models for the desired number of iterations
num_iterations = 10000

# Move all models to GPU
device = torch.device("cuda:0")  

for _ in range(num_iterations):
    model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
    model.to(device)
    criterion = nn.BCELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    num_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 64
    num_batches = len(X_train) // batch_size

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for batch in range(num_batches):
            start = batch * batch_size
            end = (batch + 1) * batch_size
            inputs = X_train[start:end].unsqueeze(0)
            labels = Y_train[start:end].unsqueeze(0)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

    models.append(model)



# Evaluate the models and select the top performers
with torch.no_grad():
    performance = []
    for model in models:
        test_outputs = model(X_test.unsqueeze(0))
        test_loss = criterion(test_outputs.squeeze(), Y_test)
        test_accuracy = ((test_outputs > 0.5).float() == Y_test).float().mean()
        performance.append((model, test_accuracy.item()))

    performance.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    top_models = [model for model, _ in performance[:5]]

# Generate new models by multiplying the top models by 20
new_models = []
for model in top_models:
    for _ in range(20):
        new_model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
        new_model.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
        new_models.append(new_model)

# Transfer the models to the GPU
for model in models:
    model.to(device)

# Transfer the top models to the GPU
for model in top_models:
    model.to(device)

# Transfer the new models to the GPU
for new_model in new_models:
    new_model.to(device)

# Save the best model from the top_models list
best_model = top_models[0]
torch.save(best_model.state_dict(), "c:/Users/zyman/Documents/ModelParameters.pt")

print(best_model.state_dict())
```

I tried adjusting the squeeze and unsqueeze sizes, but it either didn't work or i didn't try enough